# what does E mean in this function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I came across a equation as following picture shows

[image]

but I have no idea what E means in this equation, does anyone know it? can you give me a reference please?

thank you

Comment: This notation normally means the expectation of a random variable. Could you give a little more context as to where you saw this?

Comment: i saw it here https://towardsdatascience.com/pix2pix-869c17900998

Comment: In general please do not copy images of text into your question, it makes your question unsearchable, and it is hard on the eyes. Instead, use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset the equation.

Comment: If I knew how to type in that symbol, i would have done it already....

Answer (score 3):

Moving my comment to the answers section to allow this question to be marked as answered.

This notation in this context means the expectation of a random variable. A more in-depth discussion as to why the subscripts are helpful can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72613/subscript-notation-in-expectations).